# troubles getting restTemplate.exchange configured correctly

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest

Java 8, Spring 5.x

Trying to craft a function that consumes a RESTful API that returns data in XML format.

This works from a PowerShell panel:

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Credential zzzzzzzzzzzz -Headers @{"Accept"="application/xml"} -Uri https://example.com/api/entity/person/12345
```

returning a 200 and some XML as Content. So far so good.

but trying to implement the same in Java/Spring Boot microservice is proving to be quite stubborn....

```
//in AppConfig.java
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate = (RestTemplateBuilder builder) {
        return builder.setConnectionTimeout( Duration.ofMillis(9000))
                      .setReadTimeout( Duration.ofMillis(9000))
                      .build();
    }

// leaving out all the fluff
@Service
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService {

    @Autowired
    RestTemplate restTemplate;

    public ResponseEntity<Object> getPersonGivenId( String person_id) {
        logger.info(" - entered with " + person_id);
    
        String encPW = "Basic " + Base64.getEncoder()encodeToString( "xxxxx:yyyyyyyy".getBytes("UTF-8"));
        logger.info(" - encPW:" + encPW); //   prints out "Basic zzzzzzzzzzzz" so assuming this is correct
        
        String urlStr = "https://example.com/api/entity/person/" + person_id;
        logger.info(" - urlStr:" + urlStr); //   prints out "https://example.com/api/entity/person/12345" as expected
        
        try {
            URL url = new URL( urlStr);
            URI uri = new URI( url.toString());
            
            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.add( HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE,"text/html");
            headers.add( HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, encPW);
            headers.add( HttpHeaders.ACCEPT,"application/xml");
            headers.add( HttpHeaders.CACHE_CONTROL,"no-cache");
            
            HttpEntity<Object> reqquest = new HttpEntity<Object>( null, headers);
            
            ResponseEntity<Object> responnse = restTemplate.exchange( uri, httpMethod.GET, reqquest);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            logger.info( " - MalformedURLException - " + e.message);
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            logger.info( " - URISyntaxException - " + e.message);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.info( " - Exception - " + e.message);
        }
        return responnse;
    }
}
```

consistently throws 500 error and I cannot figure out why - either something blindingly obvious or fiendishly subtle.

I'm using Object here instead of Person in case something wrong with the rest of my project is throwing things off.

Any solutions/suggestions/advice/constructive critism is much appreciated.

TIA,

Still-learning Steve

UPDATE -- added AppConfig to show how restTemplate is set up , based upon a snigglet of code found elsewhere on SO

Answer (score 0):

I can see some syntax error in the code, but I guess the problem here could be  the wrong definition for exchange method.
For more information, do checkout - [Spring Rest documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html)

Here's what worked for me -

```
@Service
  public class class MyServiceImpl implements MyService {

  private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass().getName());

@Autowired
RestTemplateBuilder restTemplate;

public ResponseEntity<Object> getPersonGivenId(String person_id) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
  logger.info(" - entered with " + person_id);

  String encPW = "Basic " + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString( "xxxxx:yyyyyyyy".getBytes("UTF-8"));
  logger.info(" - encPW:" + encPW); //   prints out "Basic zzzzzzzzzzzz" so assuming this is correct

  String urlStr = "https://example.com/api/entity/person/" + person_id;
  logger.info(" - urlStr:" + urlStr); //   prints out "https://example.com/api/entity/person/12345" as expected
  ResponseEntity<Object> responnse = null;
  try {
    URL url = new URL( urlStr);
    URI uri = new URI( url.toString());

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add( HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE,"text/html");
    headers.add( HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, encPW);
    headers.add( HttpHeaders.ACCEPT,"application/xml");
    headers.add( HttpHeaders.CACHE_CONTROL,"no-cache");

    HttpEntity<Object> reqquest = new HttpEntity<Object>(null, headers);

     responnse = restTemplate.build().exchange(uri, HttpMethod.GET, reqquest, Object.class);
  } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    logger.info( " - MalformedURLException - " + e);
  } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
    logger.info( " - URISyntaxException - " + e);
  } catch (Exception e) {
    logger.info( " - Exception - " + e);
  }
  return responnse;
}


  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was indeed fiendishly subtle. Simply removing

```
headers.add( HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE,"text/html");
```

did the trick. Magic.

Thx to all that looked, spl thx to those that responded!

Still-learning Steve